# Поместить _com_ptr_t в _variant_t

Tags: c++, com

При неявном преобразовании `_com_ptr_t` в `_variant_t` - оно проходит через промежуточное преобразование к `bool` (Обнаружено через debugger. Никаких сравнении с `bool`ом, естественно, не происходит). Цепочка получается такая:
`_com_ptr_t` → `bool` → `_variant_t`
Естественно в `_variant_t` уже хранится `bool` значение, а не `IDispatch*` как должно было быть.

Такой вариант тоже не подходит:

```
_variant_t(_com_ptr_t); // все равно проходит преобразование к bool, а затем к _variant_t.
(IDispatch*)_com_ptr_t; // при этом варианте значение передаётся в перегруженную функцию принимающий параметр const bool&
```

Рабочий вариант:

```
_variant_t((IDispatch*) _com_ptr_t); // теперь в _variant_t хранится именно IDispatch*
```

Конструкция получается уродская. Просьба подсказать почему происходит неявное преобразование к `bool` и есть ли какой более красивый способ.

P.S.: Вариант с ещё одной перегруженной функцией, принимающей `IDispatch*`, и будет рассматриваться в последнюю очередь, но за неимением лучшего - будет принята. Не хочется плодить функции с одним и тем же функционалом.

### **Обновление**

*Попробовал через перегруженную функцию - все равно сначала преобразовывается в `bool`!*

### **Обновление 2**

Я передавал в перегруженную функцию const IDispatch*, как уже понакатанной, а нужно было IDispatch*. В принципе это то же самое что и бывший рабочий вариант, но теперь функции нужно передать "всего лишь" `(IDispatch*)_com_ptr_t`, что уже немного получше. Главное не забывать.

Судя по всему, коллега **ixSci** уже сказал что вариантов нет, поэтому вопрос можно считать закрытым.

Comment: А почему не через `IUnknown*`? `IDispatch*` может и не поддерживаться.

Comment: Объект которому я передаю COM указатель нуждается именно в IDispatch* (я даже специально попробовал). Видимо при передаче IUnknown* какая-то информация теряется. Преобразование написал в C варианте, т.к. символов меньше :) (т.е. static_cast<IUnknown*>(_com_ptr_t) аналогично (IUnknown*)(_com_ptr_t) Пока тестирую, как будет лучше.

Comment: @StasMyagkov, если ответ Вас удовлетворяет, пожалуйста отметьте его галочкой(рядом с ответом)

Answer (score 2):

Это происходит из-за того, что в классе `_variant_t` объявлен конструктор `_variant_t(bool)`, а в классе `_com_ptr_t` оператор приведения [`operator bool( ) const`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/803e9tsc.aspx). Стоит отметить, что в классе `_com_ptr_t` также содержится и оператор приведения `operator Interface *( ) const`, где `Interface` это собсвенно тип интерфейса которым инстанцирован `_com_ptr_t`. Но звезды складываются так, что хотя `Interface` и наследуется от `IDispatch`, в качестве "ближайшего" компилятор выбирает приведение из `bool` в `bool` и выражение `_variant_t(_com_ptr_t);` компилируется в этом варианте.

Поэтому правильно писать так, как Вы и указали в "рабочем варианте". Еще можно писать `_variant_t(_com_ptr_t.GetInterfacePtr());` если не хотите явно указывать тип для приведения.